# Android Quiz App - Make Questions Random and Dynamic

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile

I am working on building a quiz app for Android. Once completed, the app with have around 500 questions, existing in multiple categories.

I can get the questions to work fine, but only in one instance: the questions are linear, meaning that they always appear in the same order and the question always has the same answers in the same order (so, for example, Question 1 always has Answers A, B, and C, Question 2 always has Answers D, E, F, etc.) I know the reason for this since I'm just swapping textviews, basically, but only because I don't know how to do what I'm trying to do.

1. I want the questions within each set to go in a random order without duplicates. In a previous project, to accomplish something similar I created an integer that would generate a random value and then check to see if that value has been used already. However, that would be incredibly memory-inefficient and since I'm working on an Android app and not a PC one, that's too important to overlook.
2. I want each question to have random answers, other than the correct one, chosen from a pool of possible answers. So, for example, if I were to ask something like "Who ruled Britain from 1810-1820" (no actual idea on the answer), I'd want one answer to be the correct one and the other two or three to be taken from a pool of 10 European rulers. Additionally, I want the placement of the correct answer to be dynamic, so it isn't always in the same spot (so people don't just memorize the question and it's answer's location).

As of now, the questions are just in a java file since I'm still in the pre-alpha stage, but I plan on moving it to a SQLite database once I get the framework for the project figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is you should randomize the order of the quiz's array with an integer array that contain numbers from 0 to 499. all questions will shown but not in same order. to do this, see this post: [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

the second case, if I'm in your place, I will make an array of the answers, put random answers, and take a random number from 0 to 3 for the index of the right answer and

```
answer[random]=correctAnswer;
```

Regards

Comment: Putting the answers into an array and then shuffling them is a brilliant idea that I had not considered, thanks. However, another potential issue is that, for some of the questions, I will be using images instead of text. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I'm using a SQLite database to pull both the correct and incorrect answers, in the database I'll just put a uri for the image instead of just a text string, correct?

Comment: I meant shuffling the questions array or array of there indexes 0-499. (not the answers) and pick 4 of the 10 answers randomly and replace one of them with the correct answer also randomly. You can shuffling the answers too and take from 0-3. Yes, the you can put uri of the image or the image ID. I wish you finish your project ;)

Answer (score 0):

for 1)

Write down the questions from 1 to N.
Pick a random number k between one and the number of unstruck numbers remaining (inclusive).
Counting from the low end, strike out the kth question not yet struck out, and write it down elsewhere.
Repeat from step 2 until all the numbers have been struck out.
The sequence of questions written down in step 3 is now a random permutation of the original numbers.

this is nothing but.. Fischer Yates Shuffle which you could look at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code

```
//Take a list to store the index of already asked questions
HashSet<Integer> alreadyAskedQuestions = new HashSet<Integer>();

Random random = new Random();

//change the number according to your need
int maxQuestionCount = 500; 

//Continue untill all the questions are completed 
while (alreadyAskedQuestions.size() < maxQuestionCount) {

    // Get a question that is not already asked
    int currentQuestionIndex = random.nextInt(maxQuestionCount);
    while (alreadyAskedQuestions.contains(currentQuestionIndex)) {
        currentQuestionIndex = random.nextInt(maxQuestionCount);
    }

    // do something with current question

    // Put the answers into a list
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    answers.add("right answer");
    answers.add("wrong answer 1");
    answers.add("wrong answer 2");
    answers.add("wrong answer 3");

    //Shuffle the answers
    Collections.shuffle(answers);

    // do something with the answers

    // put the current question in the already asked list
    alreadyAskedQuestions.add(currentQuestionIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right,you actually need an efficient way to randomize the index at which questions are placed ....

Do this it'll give you random number efficiently

Use this number as an index to your stored questions and show them

```
int t=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
int index=t%500;

Access your question

Questions[index]
```

This will give a question always in a random order..

Hope it helps you.